# Бот телеграмма python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Написал бота в PyCharm. По сообщению фото, должны выводиться все картинки из каталога, но при отправке фото или любой другой команды, в чате пусто.

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
import config
import telebot
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'фото':
        directory = "C:\\Users\\Lamptop\\Desktop\\open"
        all_files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
        print(all_files_in_directory)
        for file in all_files_in_directory:
            img = open(directory + '/' + file, rb)
            bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id, 'upload photo')
            bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, img)
            img.close()
```

Comment: `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` писали?

Comment: Спасибо, забыл, но теперь пишет File "C:/Users/Lamptop/PycharmProjects/untitled/bot.py", line 16, in handle_text
    img = open(directory + '/' + file, rb)
NameError: name 'rb' is not defined. Что мне требуется сделать для вывода изображений из папки по тексту фото?

Comment: `rb`  взять в кавычки. То есть так - `'rb'`